# Это нормально устанавливать php одной версии, а расширения другой?

Tags: php, linux

У меня
php версии 7.2,
php-curl версии 7.3,
php xml версии 7.4

Это нормально или нужно устанавливать все одной версии?

Comment: а это версия расширения или версия пхп, для которого оно предназначено?

Comment: PHP устанавливать уже не очень нормально!

Comment: Ну если они у вас будут работать, то всё нормально. Обычно расширения несовместимых версий просто не работают (php улетает с ошибкой)

Comment: Скорее всего у Вас остались пакеты от предыдущих версий. Всегда с php ставятся пакеты с расширениями под текущую версию. То есть если версия 7.4 то и все расширения буду тоже 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если эти расширения будут работать, то да. Если расширение несовместимо с текущей версией PHP, то он попросту не загрузится и PHP выдаст соответствующее предупреждение